# Record stereo audio with Airpods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiorecorder, airpods

I'm trying Voice record from airpods using AVAudioRecorder. I know AirPods has microphone both side, but unfortunately I cant get 2 channel audio It uses just one microphone randomly... I want to get 2 channel Audio with per airpod microphone, Is there any way or it is impossible?